# How to get user styles for a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to to get these styles using javascript

[image]

`window.getComputedStyle()` returns everything including the defaults.

I need to get all of the css of an element I select, every style rule including styles that it inherited from its parent.
Basically what the devtools does.

Comment: You mean get the body and html style properties?

Comment: @SachiTekina the user styles for any element (excluding all the defaults)

Comment: Then you need to specify the element that you want to get.

Comment: I know. But what I'm asking is, how to get the user styles of an element, like on the attached image

Comment: Could you tell us exactly why you want to get them? if you want to get ALL the properties it will be a bit difficult to understand them, when you visualize a set of properties of an element in your browser's inspector, it is for a rule in CSS. Maybe what you need is to see the properties of that rule

Comment: @HugoStivenLagunaRueda I want to get the css properties of an element the same way the browser's devtools do, not including the browser's default css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getFileStyle(ele) {
  var styleSheets = document.styleSheets
  return Array.from(styleSheets).reduce((re, sheet) => {
    if (sheet.cssRules !== null) {
      var href = sheet.href
      Array.from(sheet.cssRules).reduce((r, rule) => {
        var selector = rule.selectorText
        if (Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).includes(ele)) {
          r[selector] = r[selector]
            ? [...r[selector], { css: rule.style.cssText, href }]
            : [{ css: rule.style.cssText, href }]
        }
        return r
      }, re)
    }
    return re
  }, {})
}

console.log(getFileStyle(document.body))
```

result image:
[image]

1、However,if you run the code on this page,you will get nothing because the style SO used are coming from a different domain.

> In some browsers, if a stylesheet is loaded from a different domain,
>   calling cssRules results in SecurityError.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)

2、your question is not clear because you should give us an expected output not the image.The image only show the applicable style rules while the the applicable style rules will change in some situation.

For example,if you resize the window to 300*300 just like on the mobile. The style you see may change because other style rules may be applicable.

So, my code can't give you the realtime applicable rules.It is very troublesome.

3、In most situation ,`getComputedStyle` is enough.If you have to deal with  `styleSheets` I think there is always another easy way.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.
I think I'll just proxy cross domain stylesheets and see if it works